# X11-Forward a Windows program to Linux

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

On Linux, you can use the `X11Forwarding` Option in SSH to have a program run on PC A but get the program's window on PC B. I'd like to do that from Windows to Linux - I have a Windows-only program on my Windows PC, and like to have an SSH server on that Windows computer so that I can use SSH on my Linux Laptop to use that program.

However when I search the internet for X11 forwarding on Windows & Linux I only find solutions on how to install an X server in Windows to use a Linux tool in Windows. I'd like to use a Windows tool in Linux.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, but you could share the whole desktop of the windows box via RDP (tunneled over ssh)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. The windows applications are using completely different (and closed) technology, which is not in any way compatible with X11, therefore you can't put it this way.

As already mentioned, the only way to go is to use RDP (or SSH-tunnelled RDP) or some kind of VNC (should be also some version for Windows).